# MySQL - Count values of a column ordered by other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to achieve this table:

---

```
|Country|Cars|Blue Cars|Red Cars| Green Cars |
|Mexico | 22 |    12   |   8    |     2      |
|U.S.A  | 12 |    6    |   3    |     3      |
|Denmark| 10 |    3    |   2    |     5      |
```

That from a database table that makes a report (row) for every car, like this:

```
|Country|car_color|
|Mexico | Blue    |    
|U.S.A  | Red     |    
|Denmark| Blue    | 
|Denmark| Blue    |
|Mexico | Blue    |
|Denmark| Green   |
|Denmark| Red     |
|U.S.A  | Red     |
|Denmark| Green   |
```

I did the first part: grouping the countries and get the total number of cars by country, that was with this query:

```
SELECT country,
       COUNT(county)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY COUNT(country)
```

My question is, how do I get the color car columns in the first table after grouping the rows by county and getting the total number of cars by every country?

Note: I tried several ways but I'm failing to achieve this. As an example, I used:

```
SELECT country,
       COUNT(country),
       COUNT(case when car_color = 'Green' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY COUNT(country)
```

But that only shows the same value of Cars (total number of cars in a country) for the column "Green Car".

Help please!

Comment: MySQL and/or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 3):

`COUNT` counts non-NULL rows and your `CASE` always returns a value.

Either switch to `SUM` or omit the `ELSE` part:

```
 SELECT country
  ,COUNT(*) AS cars 
  ,SUM(case when car_color = "blue" then 1 else 0 end) AS "blue cars" 
  ,SUM(case when car_color = "red" then 1 else 0 end) AS "red cars"
  ,COUNT(case when car_color = "green" then 1 end) AS "green cars"
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: In mysql this  can be shorten to `..SUM(car_color = "blue" )..`

Comment: @Mihai: Why should I use some proprietary syntax if there's an alternative syntax using Standard SQL. Save some keystrokes and learn non-portable SQL?

Comment: Sure you\`re right,but it`s good to know this is also an option.

Comment: Changing to SUM, with the code you wrote here, worked perfectly! Thanks dnoeth.

Comment: In MySQL, the simplest way is really `SUM(car_color = 'blue')`.